# How to Configure a column not to visible by default in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, multiple-columns, hide

I want to hide one column and make the column visdible but if user want the user view the column, i tried this way but did not worked forr me.

admin.py

```
class ProductAdmin(TimestampedModelAdminMixin, ConfigurableColumnsMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):


list_display = [
           "id",
          "comment",
           "active",
          ]
```

I tried with this way but did not worked.

```
 def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(ProductAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    del form.base_fields["comment"]
    return form
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the fields that you want to show in the `fieldset` in the admin class.
You can refer to docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets)

Generic syntax for fieldset (from the docs)

```
class FlatPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'fields': ('url', 'title', 'content', 'sites')
    }),
    ('Advanced options', {
        'classes': ('collapse',),
        'fields': ('registration_required', 'template_name'),
    }),
)
```

The code in your case would be -:

```
class ProductAdmin(TimestampedModelAdminMixin:
    fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'fields': ('id', 'active')
    })
    
    )
```

Comment: can you please  give little more specific

Comment: @ SwapnilChopra really sorry , which fileld will hide the column

Comment: In the fieldset option, we can specify the fields that needs to be shown, and if you want to do this dynamically, you can override the get_fieldset method of the admin class

Comment: can you please share the code you are telling

Comment: @swapnichopra are you there, if you can write that code that would be really helpful

Comment: @abolfazlmalekahmadi are you there

Comment: Yeah, I am back. I have edited my answer, give it a try and let me know. There are plenty of methods to accomplish what you are asking for.